# PHP How to check if a file with a list of string contain a full word

Tags: php, string

I want to check if this kind of file contain a full string :

> Jack
>
> Marion
>
> Paul

I have this code, but if **$first_name** is only "Ma", then $valid is 1...

```
$handle = fopen('firstname.txt', 'r');
$valid = 0; // init as false
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($buffer, ucfirst($first_name)) !== false) {
        $valid = 1;
    }      
}
fclose($handle);
```

How to check if only "Marion" (in full) will work ?

Comment: Can you accept my answer please? That will 'pay' me with stackoverflow reputation point :-)

Comment: I did, but I have this message : Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: With my upvote on your question, you have more than 15 reputation score (number in bold at right of your profile picture). So now your vote are publicly use  :-)

Comment: I think you need to click on gray tick to accept answer ([Help of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). Arrows up and down are for voting, who is allow only with stackoverflow reputation system

Comment: Perfect! Thank for accepting my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encapsulate separator (coma-point, @, # ,...) to your names in data source.
After add them in your test, remove ucfirst function and convert to upper case (only for test).
With this way, character case of first names in your text file 'firstname.txt' don't matter

> @Jack@
>
> @mArioN@
>
> @pAuL@

```
// Define separator
$separator = '@';
// Pre-calculation of test first name
$firstNameTest = $separator . strtoupper($first_name) . $separator;
$handle = fopen('firstname.txt', 'r');
$valid = 0; // init as false
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // Test upper case buffer versus pre-calculated first name
    if (strpos(strtoupper($buffer), $firstNameTest) !== false) {
        $valid = 1;
    }      
}
fclose($handle);
```

> **Update** (without altering source file)

If source file cannot be altered, an other way could be to add a carriage return at the end of your `$first_name`.

```
// Pre-calculation of test first name
$firstNameTest = strtoupper($first_name) . PHP_EOL;
$handle = fopen('firstname.txt', 'r');
$valid = 0; // init as false
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // Test upper case buffer versus pre-calculated first name
    if (strpos(strtoupper($buffer), $firstNameTest) !== false) {
        $valid = 1;
    }      
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I can't edit the data source, as it's already used by another scripts...

Comment: I added a other script with a carriage return at the end. I'm not sure if that's working, but worth a try